# (solaris) ld: fatal: ... version 'GCC_4.2.0' does not exist

Tags: c++, gcc, linker

I'm trying to compile a c++ program for the first time on this machine (which is not mine), so I've written a simple hello world. My command to compile gets an error,

```
>g++ testing.cpp -L/usr/local/lib
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so: version 'GCC_4.2.0' does not exist:
    required by file /usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so
```

but I have something there:

```
>file /usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so
/usr/local/lib/libgcc_s.so:     ELF 32-bit LSB dynamic lib 80386 Version 1 [FPU], dynamically linked, not stripped
```

For giggles if I do any of these:

```
>g++ testing.cpp
>g++ testing.cpp -L/usr/sfw/bin
>g++ testing.cpp -L/local/bin
```

I get this same exact error (directory does not change, probably because there's no libgcc_s in bin?):

```
ld: fatal: file /usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.3.3/../../../libgcc_s.so: version 'GCC_4.2.0' does not exist:
    required by file /usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/4.3.3/../../../libstdc++.so
```

Located in `/usr/local/lib/gcc/i386-pc-solaris2.10/` I see `3.4.6` and `4.3.3`.

And I see that a symlink of `/usr/local/lib/libcc_s.so` points to `libgcc_s.so.1` created in 2001...

I saw elsewhere the following way to check the version, but it returns nothing:

```
/usr/local/lib>strings libgcc_s.so.1 | grep GCC
```

My questions are:

1. What exactly is going on? Does the linker accept "kinda old" libraries but reject really old ones, like 2001? Will the linker ever get upset at too NEW of a version?
2. Is there any way to tell what version the libgcc_so is?
3. Can I cheat and force it to use the currently installed version by creating a symlink? If so, what symlink should I create?

Thank you for reading and for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow. I feel very silly. All I needed to do was specify the particular version of g++ to use by changing my command to

```
/usr/sfw/bin/g++ testing.cpp
```

Ta-da! Program compiles and runs successfully.

In case anyone else has this problem, it might help to run `which g++` and try the various options.

```
>which g++ 
g++ is /usr/local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/sfw/bin/g++
g++ is /local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/sfw/bin/g++
g++ is /local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/sfw/bin/g++
g++ is /local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/local/bin/g++
g++ is /usr/sfw/bin/g++ 
g++ is /local/bin/g++
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting gcc libraries, Check the version of OS(32/64 bit) and install gcc libs accordingly.

Comment: Hm. I'm trying to use the existing libraries, as they've been one the machine for years and other programs compiled OK just a few years ago. (Also, even though it's 64bit, I've tried using the `-m32` flag in my compiler command, and it doesn't change the error.) Thanks though.

Comment: btw, the response you gave here wasn't really an answer... next time maybe consider a comment instead.